# URI problem in PYQGIS

Tags: python, qgis, plugins

I am working with python plugins for **qgis**.I developed the plugin same as **rt sql layer** and incooperated the same in **qgis**.
Its opening fine when i run qgis exe.But on my **ok** button ,i have following code to form **layer**.

```
# create the layer                      
            uri = self.db.getURI()
            uri.setDataSource("", "(" + query + ")", geomFieldName, "", uniqueFieldName)
            vl = self.iface.addVectorLayer(uri.uri(), newLayerName, self.db.getProviderName())

            QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()

            if vl and vl.isValid():
                    self.saveQuery()
                    self.accept()
```

**getURI()** is defined in another form as follows:

```
def getURI(self):
            # returns a new QgsDataSourceURI instance

            return qgis.core.QgsDataSourceURI( self.uri.connectionInfo() )
```

On click of **ok** button it gives me error saying

```
 return qgis.core.QgsDataSourceURI( self.uri.connectionInfo() )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connectionInfo'
```

what should **URI** contain??

Comment: These questions are not GIS-specific but rather general programming questions. I'm therefore migrating them to the appropriate Stackexchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like self.uri in getURI() is not initialized. Have you checked this? Your snippets do not allow to reproduce the problem. Try to post the code where self.uri is filled (and check that this part is actually executed).